# Probability Density Function in R

Tags: r

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help me as I'm new to R and struggling to work out how to write in equations or to find a function that is already ingrained in R.

So I am currently trying to create a probability density function that generates a random sample of 50,000 draws from the U(0,1) distribution by alternating the values of beta and micro in my formula, naturally as long as beta > 0
[image]

I think I should be starting with

> m=50000  #where m is the number of draws

> runif(m,0,1)

And here's where I get into a bit of a rut and hence I am wondering if anyone could help me out on how to do this.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Check `density` function. It could help you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have found the function >dnorm  which I believe returns the probability density function but Im not entirely sure how to manipulate this in order to use my equation. Could you advance further on your comment at all?